# Random forest regressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark

I was trying to use random forest regressor, but there is an error message at the rf line

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

va = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(diamonds_df_xformed.columns([-4,]).setOutputCol('features')

# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)

(trainingData, testData) = diamonds_df_xformed.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a RandomForest model.
rf = RandomForestRegressor(labelCol="price",featuresCol="features")
```

I got an error as the graph shows, I wonder what is the problem in this case error message.

[image]

Comment: you haven't imported `RandomForestRegressor`, you have imported `RandomForestClassifier`

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter; same hold true for irrelevant imports. Finally, be more careful with your code formatting, otherwise you may create misunderstandings as in comment above (edited).